# Como fazer um JDialog ficar invisível quando dou dispose em um frame específico?

Tags: java, swing, jdialog

Um botão de minha aplicação dá `dispose` no frame atual e cria outro diferente. Mas os `JDialog` que estavam abertos quando clico no botão continuam existindo, o que não deveria acontecer.

Comment: poderia dar mais informação sobre seu problema? se puder poste o código em que está tendo o problema

Comment: Se eu entendi seu problema, um `Window Listener` adicionado ao JFrame que está aberto pode resolver seu problema.

Comment: Window Listener resolveu o problema, obrigado...